# How to get current product in magento 2 observer without registry

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento2.4.5, registry

I need to get the current product details in magento2 observer without using the registry.because magento latest version is deprecated this registry.
I need the current product for reviews. when submit the form send the email

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on the event you are observering. Events can be fired from anywhere and usually have data assigned to the event itself - it may not always be the case that a product is defined in the registry when an event is fired.

If you are working with an event like `catalog_product_save_after` for example, you can access the product being saved like:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer): void
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
    if (!$product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface) {
        return;
    }
    
    // We now have a valid $product, do whatever with it.
    $product->setData('foo', 'bar');
}
```

**EDIT:**

As you've mentioned in comments, it appears the event in question is `review_save_after`. The below code should work in your observer class:

```php
/* @var $review \Magento\Review\Model\Review */
$review = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
foreach ($review->getProductCollection() as $product) {
    // We now have access to each $product associated to the review.
    $product->setData('foo', 'bar');
};
```

Comment: Do you know the name of the event you are observing? It should be defined in your modules `events.xml` file.

Comment: event name="review_save_after"

Comment: I've updated my answer in relation to review_save_after event.

Comment: Hi, it is set the data to product attribute. I need to get the current product details

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the deprecated here is just a notice, and It stands in code for a long time, I'm using it day-by-day tasks and have no consequences, the registry still contains the data, so why not,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Registry, you can try using $this->request->getParams().

You can get id in params,

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

For Product Id,

```
$this->request->getParam('product_id'); // Use this class in construct() \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
```

**In your Controller file**

```
protected $request;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

public function execute()
{
    $this->request->getParam('product_id');
}
```

**To get id in getParam() you need to pass it as hidden field in phtml file**

In your phtml file,

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id ?>">
```

**In Observer & Plugin File**:- It depends on which event you want to observe and same goes for the plugin. If you're passing as hidden field and calling a observer on that particular event, you can get id as i mentioned above.